# XML file is missing when I sending XML data in API as post request using php curl?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am getting the error "XML file is missing" when I post the XML data using CURL in PHP. And,
I used many of the articles of StackOverflow but doesn't work out for me. Please help me out!

Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');

$results = getAPIResult();
echo($results);
?>
```

The following function is used for executing CURL

```
<?php
function getAPIResult() {
        $user = array(
                "user" => "test",
                "pass" => "test@123"
            );

    $xml = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?> <Data xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"><DataID></DataID><DataName></DataName><DataDisplayName><![CDATA[Test display name]]></DataDisplayName></Data>';

    $curlObj = curl_init();

    $options = [
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://domainname/login",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
                CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt',
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($user),
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Expect:'],
                CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
                CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_COOKIE => "cookiename=0",
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7",
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            ];

    curl_setopt_array($curlObj, $options);

    $returnData = curl_exec($curlObj);

    if (curl_errno($curlObj)) {
        //error message
        $returnData = curl_error($curlObj);
    }

    $apiURL = 'https://domainname/api/data';
    //Actual API URL is "https://domainname/api/data?action=create&source=" and gave xml source data.

            $post_data = array(
                "action" => "create",
                "source" => $xml,
            );

            if ($apiURL != "") {
                curl_setopt_array($curlObj, array(
                    CURLOPT_URL => $apiURL,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
                    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt',
                ));

             if (is_array($post_data) && count($post_data) > 0) {
                    curl_setopt_array($curlObj, array(
                        CURLOPT_POST => true,
                        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_data),
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    ));
                }

          $returnData = curl_exec($curlObj);

    if (curl_errno($curlObj)) {
        //error message
        $returnData = curl_error($curlObj);
    }

    curl_close($curlObj);

    return $returnData;

    }
?>
```

Please let me know, why its not working? and I am getting the XML file is missing error.

Comment: Did you try executing a CURL request or tested it on  REST client like POSTMAN?

Comment: Both way I tried it and getting the same error!

Comment: I'm sure this problem is on the endpoint you are requesting data to.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi, I agreed. then, I send data as parameters like actual endpoint: Ex: "https://domainname/api/data?action=create&source=$xml" 
Still, the issue persists.

Comment: Can you reveal the api endpoint so that I can assist you better and resolve the issue

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi, Sorry, it's the confidential one. I gave that example is similar to the real one. Any other way?

Comment: I guess the only way I know right now is maybe you can screenshot the error and post It here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212959/discussion-between-sachin-bahukhandi-and-ramesh-moorthy).